# Passing typed array as any[]?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

Why can't I pass a typed array into a function/constructor which takes an `any[]`?

```
typedArray = new MyType[ ... ];
items = new ko.observableArray(typedArray);
```

Gives me the error:

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

`ko.observableArray` is defined as:

```
interface KnockoutStatic 
{
    observableArray: KnockoutObservableArrayStatic;
}

interface KnockoutObservableArrayStatic
{
    new(value: any[]): KnockoutObservableArray;
}

declare var ko: KnockoutStatic;
```

How do I pass my `MyType[]` as an `any[]`? Is this a problem with covariance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedArray = new MyType[ ... ];
```

This isn't how you make a new array in JavaScript or TypeScript (in 0.9.0 this will correctly be a syntax error in the empty array case). You should just be able to write:

```
typedArray = [ ... ];
```

and have the compiler correctly infer the type as `MyType[]`. If needed, you can add a type annotation:

```
typedArray = <MyType[]>[ ... ];
```